# Problemas com scanf e printf em C++

Tags: c++

Estou com um programa na qual preciso armazenar um array de uma classe musica que gera uma lista com as musicas e suas características.
O problema e que na hora do método de imprimir ela gera uma confusão dos caracteres, ou misturando ou omitindo parte deles.Já tentei diversos métodos e nada deu certo.
Poderiam me ajudar?

**Esse e o main.cpp**

```html
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "musica.h"
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    int TAMMP3=0;

 musica mp3, *musica_op;

 musica_op = (musica*) malloc (1 * sizeof(musica));

    int choice = 1;

    do {

     mp3 = musica();

     mp3.lerdados();

     musica_op[TAMMP3] = mp3;




     if(choice == 1) {
      musica_op = (musica*) realloc(musica_op,(TAMMP3+2) * sizeof(musica));
   TAMMP3++;
  }

  cout<<"Deseja adicionar uma musica?\nDigite 1 para sim e 0 para nao :";
     cin>>choice;

 } while (choice == 1);

    for(int i = 0; i < TAMMP3; i++) {
     musica_op[i].imprimir();
 }



    return 0;
}

#endif
```

**Esse e o musica.h**

```html
#ifndef MUSICA_H
#define MUSICA_H

class musica {
public:
musica ();
~musica ();
char *GetNome_musica();
void SetNome_musica(char * m_nome_musica);
float GetDuracao_musica();
void SetDuracao_musica(float m_duracao_musica);
char *GetAlbum_musica();
void SetAlbum_musica(char *m_album_musica);
float GetKbps_musica();
void SetKbps_musica(float m_kbps_musica);
void SetAno(int m_ano);
int GetAno();
char *GetArtista();
void SetArtista(char *m_artista);
char *GetGenero();
void SetGenero(char *m_genero);
void lerdados ();
void imprimir();

   private:
    char * nome_musica;
    float duracao_musica;
    char * album_musica;
    float kbps_musica;
    int ano;
    char * artista;
    char * genero;
};
#endif
```

**E esse e o musica.cpp**

```html
#include "musica.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

musica::musica(){
 nome_musica = (char*) malloc (70*sizeof (char));
 album_musica = (char*) malloc (70*sizeof (char));
 artista = (char*) malloc (70*sizeof (char));
 genero = (char*) malloc (70*sizeof (char));


}

musica::~musica(){}

void musica::SetNome_musica(char * m_nome_musica) {
    nome_musica = m_nome_musica ;
}
char * musica::GetNome_musica() {
    return nome_musica ;
}

void musica::SetAlbum_musica(char * m_album_musica) {
    album_musica = m_album_musica;
}

char * musica::GetAlbum_musica() {
    return album_musica;
}


void musica::SetArtista(char * m_artista) {
    artista = m_artista;
}
char * musica::GetArtista() {
    return artista;
}

void musica::SetGenero(char * m_genero) {
    genero = m_genero;
}
char * musica::GetGenero() {
    return genero;
}

void musica::SetDuracao_musica(float m_duracao_musica) {
    duracao_musica = m_duracao_musica;
}
float musica::GetDuracao_musica() {
    return duracao_musica;
}

void musica::SetKbps_musica(float m_kbps_musica) {
    kbps_musica = m_kbps_musica;
}
float musica::GetKbps_musica() {
    return kbps_musica;
}

void musica::SetAno(int m_ano) {
    ano = m_ano;
}
int musica::GetAno() {
    return ano;
}





void musica::imprimir() {



printf ("Nome da musica:%s"".mp3"" \nDuracao da musica:%10.2f\n Album da musica:%s \n "
        "Kbps da musica:%10.2f \n Ano da musica:%d \n Nome do artista:%s \n Nome do genero:%s \n"
        ,&nome_musica,duracao_musica,&album_musica,kbps_musica,ano,&artista,&genero);
}

void musica::lerdados() {
    printf("Informe o nome da musica:\n");
    scanf (" %[^\n]s",&nome_musica);
    printf("Informe a duracao da musica:\n");
    scanf (" %f",&duracao_musica);
    printf("Informe o nome do album:\n");
    scanf (" %[^\n]s",&album_musica);
    printf("Informe o Kbps da musica:\n");
    scanf (" %f",&kbps_musica);
    printf("Informe o ano da musica:\n");
    scanf (" %d",&ano);
    printf("Informe o artista da musica:\n");
    scanf (" %[^\n]s",&artista);
    printf("Informe o genero da musica:\n");
    scanf (" %[^\n]s",&genero);
}
```

Comment: Sugiro reduzir a questão a um exemplo pequeno e verificavel, pois como tem está muito extenso e torna mais dificil de dar uma resposta. Logo se quer uma resposta e rápida faça uma questão direta e concreta apenas com o código relevante ao problema. Em relação ao código em si o `printf` dentro de `imprimir` utiliza `%s` mas depois passa um endereço de uma `string`, que não está certo : `printf ("Nome da musica:%s....\n",&nome_musica, ...` quando `nome_musica` é do tipo `char*`, logo deveria passar apenas `nome_musica`.

Comment: Ola. Não entendi muito bem sua resposta. Mas vou exemplificar. Ele faz a coleta dos dados em vetor do objeto musica. Porem na hora de imprimir o coletado ele apresenta omissao de parte do coletado.O nome so pega 8 caracteres sendo que foi passado o limite de 70.

Comment: O que eu disse é que não está a chamar o `printf` corretamente. Confirme os placeholders e os valores associados. Não sei se esse será o unico erro pois o código é muito extenso e não o vi todo, mas pelo menos essa parte precisa de ser corrigida.

Comment: Cara, dá uma olhada nessa atribuição aqui: mp3 = musica();

Comment: Você tem que definir seus construtores direito. E sobrecarregar o operador de atribuição. A cópia que está sendo feita é cópia por valor, ele está copiando endereço de memória. Quando destroi o objeto criado do lado direito, apaga tudo do seu objeto do lado esquerdo da atribuicao. Vai imprimir lixo, na melhor das hipóteses.

Answer (score 1):

Em `C++`, [tente evitar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2872543/printf-vs-cout-in-c) o uso das funções `printf()` e `scanf()`! Elas podem ser perfeitamente substituidas por `std::cout` e `std::cin`, respectivamente.

O mesmo acontece com strings, ao invés de usar um ponteiro `char*` apontando para uma área de memória alocada com `malloc()`, você pode simplesmente usar `std::string`.

Seu método `imprimir()` pode ser substituido pelo operador `<<`.

Veja só como tudo pode ser mais simples e legível:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Musica
{
    public:

        Musica( void ) : m_duracao(0.0), m_kbps(0.0), m_ano(0) {}
        virtual ~Musica(void) {}

        void nome(std::string nome) { m_nome = nome; }
        std::string nome(void) { return m_nome; }

        void album( std::string album ) { m_album = album; }
        std::string album(void) { return m_album; }

        void artista(std::string artista) { m_artista = artista; }
        std::string artista(void) { return m_artista; }

        void genero(std::string genero) { m_genero = genero; }
        std::string genero(void) { return m_genero; }

        void duracao(float duracao) { m_duracao = duracao; }
        float duracao(void) { return m_duracao; }

        void kbps(float kbps) { m_kbps = kbps; }
        float kbps(void) { return m_kbps; };

        void ano(int ano) { m_ano = ano; }
        int ano(void) { return m_ano; }

        void lerdados( void )
        {
            std::cout << "Informe o nome da musica:" << std::endl;
            std::getline(std::cin, m_nome);

            std::cout << "Informe a duracao da musica:" << std::endl;
            std::cin >> m_duracao;

            std::cout << "Informe o nome do album:" << std::endl;
            std::cin.ignore();
            std::getline(std::cin, m_album);

            std::cout << "Informe o Kbps da musica:" << std::endl;
            std::cin >> m_kbps;

            std::cout << "Informe o ano da musica:" << std::endl;
            std::cin >> m_ano;

            std::cout << "Informe o artista da musica:" << std::endl;
            std::cin.ignore();
            std::getline(std::cin, m_artista);

            std::cout << "Informe o genero da musica:" << std::endl;
            std::getline(std::cin, m_genero);

            std::cout << std::endl;
        }

        friend std::ostream &operator<<( std::ostream &out, Musica obj )
        {
            out << "Musica:" << std::endl;
            out << "    Nome: " << obj.m_nome << std::endl;
            out << "    Duracao: " << obj.m_duracao << " segs" << std::endl;
            out << "    Album: " << obj.m_album << std::endl;
            out << "    Kbps: " <<  obj.m_kbps << " Kbps" << std::endl;
            out << "    Ano: " << obj.m_ano << std::endl;
            out << "    Artista: " << obj.m_artista << std::endl;
            out << "    Nome do genero: " << obj.m_genero << std::endl;

            return out;
        }

    private:

        std::string m_nome;
        float m_duracao;
        std::string m_album;
        float m_kbps;
        int m_ano;
        std::string m_artista;
        std::string m_genero;
};


int main( void )
{
    Musica m;
    m.lerdados();
    std::cout << m;
    return 0;
}
```

Saída:

```
$ ./musica 
Informe o nome da musica:
Time
Informe a duracao da musica:
408
Informe o nome do album:
The Dark Side of The Moon
Informe o Kbps da musica:
256
Informe o ano da musica:
1973
Informe o artista da musica:
Pink Floyd
Informe o genero da musica:
Rock

Musica:
    Nome: Time
    Duracao: 408 segs
    Album: The Dark Side of The Moon
    Kbps: 256 Kbps
    Ano: 1973
    Artista: Pink Floyd
    Nome do genero: Rock
```